# Using Postgres CTE inside subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to use subquery with CTE using postgres, but the query is wrong. The main question is: Can I use cte inside my subquery - `revenue` inside window expression? Or maybe there's another solution to get the same result.

This was taken from the postgres excersise: https://pgexercises.com/questions/aggregates/classify.html

But I want to use cte here.

```
WITH agg AS
  (SELECT name,
          sum(CASE
                  WHEN memid = 0 THEN slots * guestcost
                  ELSE slots * membercost
              END) AS revenue
   FROM cd.bookings b
   JOIN cd.facilities f ON b.facid = f.facid
   GROUP BY name)
SELECT name,
       (CASE
            WHEN rank = 1 THEN 'high'
            WHEN rank = 2 THEN 'average'
            ELSE 'low'
        END) AS revenue1
FROM (
     SELECT name, ntile(3) OVER(ORDER BY revenue DESC) AS rank
FROM agg;
) AS agg2;
```

**UPDATE:**

The CTE is written correctly, but as I understood I can't write something like this (after cte):

```
select name from (
    select name
        from agg;
) as agg2;
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't caused by the semicolon in the second to last line?

Comment: Also when you say the query is wrong, it would be useful if you could say exactly how so: are you getting the wrong results, or a syntax error (and if so, which), etc

Comment: updated my question, see above. I'm talking about the structure of query, and maybe some namespacing

Comment: As @GordonLinoff already pointed out, get rid of the `;` in the inner query. `;` are used to terminate most outer statements. They must not be used for inner statements. I.e., change `FROM agg;` to `FROM agg`. Other than that you should be perfectly able to use CTEs in any sub query you want.

Comment: It is! Thank you guys